# Laravel login get NULL parameters

Tags: php, authentication, parameters, null, laravel

I'm trying laravel and php, and i have a problem with the login:

I have the view:

```
      {{ Form::open('login', 'POST') , ['class' => 'navbar-form navbar-right'] }}

            <div class="form-group">

                {{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username'), ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">

             {{  Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control'])        }}

            </div>

            {{ Form::submit('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
            <a class="btn btn-success" href="../registrarse">registrarse</a>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

and the route:

```
Route::post('/login', function(){
 $userdata = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );

    /* Try to authenticate the credentials */
    if(Auth::attempt($userdata)) 
    {
        // we are now logged in, go to admin
        return "oola";
    }
    else
    {
        return $userdata;
        return Redirect::to('registrarse');
    }});
```

I allways obtain:

```
{"username":null,"password":null}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for `Form::open()`is not correct. Check the following:

http://laravel.com/docs/html#opening-a-form

Basically you should do something like

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login')) }}
```

The method is optional and defaults to POST.